# Selecting more than 1000000 rows from table with SQL, Python, Numpy, Pandas, and ODBC

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy, odbc

I have a database that I need to extract a million rows from, the problem is I cannot select more than 100000 at a time. And when I do 100000, the query takes very long, up to 10 minutes to execute. This needs to be done once a day, so it is not a problem for the final project, but it is for debugging

The following code works to select 100000 rows and create a Numpy array, which turns into a Pandas dataframe.

How can I extend it to run several times to select 1000000 rows by continuously either by appending to `table_array`, to `df`, or can I just append to the `cursor` directly with a few more lines of SQL?

What I tried so far without success is `cursor.execute( "DECLARE @ count int; SET @ count = (SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM vYield; SELECT TOP(@count) * FROM vYield")`

A note here is that I dont know how many rows the database may have, I am assuming if it's less than 1000000, it will return the maximum number of rows and not crash. In this situation, I just want to append the maximum number of rows total

```
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server +
                  ';DATABASE='+database+';ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';PWD=' + password + ';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("select top 100000 * from vYield")

    table_array = numpy.empty((0, 3))

    with open('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dataout.txt', 'w') as f:
        sys.stdout = f  # Change the standard output to the file we created
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
            table_array = numpy.append(
                table_array, numpy.array([[row[27], row[8], row[19]]]), axis=0)
            row = cursor.fetchone()

    table_array = table_array[table_array[:, 0].argsort()]
    df = pandas.DataFrame(table_array, columns=['Serial', 'Test', 'Fail'])
```

Comment: The source DB data should have a `rowid`, so then in your script you could save the last record id from last 100k `select` query to ensure uniqueness.